# Double INNER JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table i'm trying to INNER JOIN twice. Here's my example:

```
Table1:
id1, id2, otherInfo

Table2:
id, Name, phone, address
```

In this example, I need to get the name and phone for id1 and id2. How do I accomplish this? How do I handle if id1 = 0?

Comment: Use table alias for the second inner join. And what do you mean by id1=0? 0 is just a number in SQL. (Perhaps you mean NULL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `inner join`:

```
select t2.name
     , t2.phone
     , t3.name
     , t3.phone
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id
join table2 t3 on t1.id2 = t3.id
```

In case `id1` or `id2` can be `null`, use `left join` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
select t1.otherInfo
    , t2.Name
    , t2.Phone
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id1 OR t2.id = t1.id2
```